# SoapUI getting request parameters in mock service script

Tags: xml, web-services, groovy, soapui

This is probably a very easy one for all SoapUI regulars.

In a SoapUI mock service response script, how do I extract the value inside the request I'm replying to?

Let's say the incoming request has

```
<ns1:foo>
  <ns3:data>
    <ns3:CustomerNumber>1234</ns3:CustomerNumber>
  </ns3:data>
</ns1:foo>
```

How do I get the "1234" into a Groovy variable? I tried with an xmlHolder but I seem to have the wrong XPath.

(I know how to set a property and integrate its value into the response already.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to access SOAP request and do some XPath processing, there's an easier way to do it in soapUI thanks to the power of [GPath](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GPath) and [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html).

Here's how you would access the customer number:

```
def req = new XmlSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContent)
log.info "Customer #${req.foo.data.CustomerNumber}"
```

As of Groovy 1.6.3 (which is used in soapUI 2.5 and beyond), XmlSlurper runs in namespace-aware and non-validating mode by default so there's nothing else you need to do.

Cheers!
Shonzilla

Comment: Plenty of XML-Q/A here, but if you have a JSON request, it works similarly using `def requestJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContent)` and e.g. `log.info "${requestJson.'CustomerNumber'}"`

Answer (score 24):

One more example:

```
def request = new XmlSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContent)
def a = request.Body.Add.x.toDouble()
def b = request.Body.Add.y.toDouble()
context.result = a + b
```

In this example we get two parameters from the request and convert them to doubles. This way we can perform calculations on the parameters. The sample SoapUI response for this example is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://example.org/math/types/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ:AddResponse>
         <result>${result}</result>
      </typ:AddResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You can see how the calculations result is passed back to the response.

Comment: Thanks for your example! I like both the replies from Shonzilla and you!

Answer (score 0):

In a pure Java (not using SoapUI) you would just create a custom Naming Context like this one:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;

class WSNamespaceContext implements NamespaceContext
{
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix)
    {
        if ( prefix.equals("ns3") )
            return "http://www.mysite.com/services/taxservice";
       else if (prefix.equals("soapenv"))
            return "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
        else
            return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
    }

    public String getPrefix(String namespace)
    {
        if ( namespace.equals("http://www.mysite.com/services/taxservice") )
            return "ns3";
        else if (namespace.equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"))
            return "soapenv";
        else
            return null;
    }

    public Iterator<List<String>> getPrefixes(String namespace)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, parse it like so:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance(); 
XPath xp = factory.newXPath(); 
xp.setNamespaceContext( nsc ); 
XPathExpression xpexpr = xp.compile("//ns3:CustomerNumber/text()");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xpexpr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); 
for ( int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++ )  { 
    String val = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
    System.out.println( "Value: " + val  ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending http://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/creating-dynamic-mockservices.html and based on http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/xmlholder.html I came up with this:

```
// Create XmlHolder for request content
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( mockRequest.requestContent )
holder.namespaces["ns3"] = "ns3"

// Get arguments
def custNo = holder.getNodeValue("//ns3:CustomerNumber")
context.setProperty("custNo", custNo)
```