# soapUI Script features

Tags: soapui

What are the functionalities in soapUI that can be achieved only through script and not the GUI

Comment: Is there anything specific that you are for?

Answer (score 1):

With scripting you can:

- setup the test environment (e.g. prepare test data, initialize test conditions)
- dynamically create requests (using current date, generating IDs, insert random values)
- script complex test cases, pass the parameters/results between steps
- you can do looping, e.g. take a list of files and send them as requests
- create reports of the tests, save the test requests and responses
- write custom assertions/validations of the responses
- compare actual responses with expected responses
- create dynamic mock services: choose or create responses programatically
- you can simulate any expected activity, e.g. if you don't have a complete test environment which would do it otherwise
- and much more.

What is importat you can tailor your tests according to your needs, thus make them much more valid and effective.

See [SoapUI docs](https://www.soapui.org/docs/scripting-and-properties/tips-tricks/) for some examples.

Comment: is there a place where to find some examples?

Comment: @Joe, yes, I have added the link to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that you can achieve using Groovy scripting is building dynamic responses in mocked services. You can find an example in the following question:

[SoapUI getting request parameters in mock service script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945403/soapui-getting-request-parameters-in-mock-service-script/1141843#1141843)