# Return a certain response in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I have created a Mock Service in SoapUI. By default it creates a `Request 1` and a corresponding `Response 1` in the Mock Service for you.

I can also *clone* `Response 1` and call it `Response 2`. But when i do a new test request in SoapUI with `Request 1`, it will then always return `Response 1`.

So what is the use of cloning ***Responses***? Is there anyway to tell SoapUI that if a request with `<ID> == 100`, then return `Response 1`, otherwise return `Response 2`.

Is this possible? If so, how can i do this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920517/how-to-return-dynamic-response-in-soapui-mockservice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double click an operation of your Mock Service. At the bottom left you will see a property called **Dispatch**. There you can choose how to dispatch your Mock Responses.

If you want to return a certain response for some value in the request you can set up an XPath expression or a Groovy Script to analyze your request.

Have a look at the following tutorial on the soapUI homepage:
http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/simulating-complex-behaviour.html