# In a SoapUI mock service response script i need to use a value from a request

Tags: xml, web-services, groovy, request, soapui

In a SoapUI mock service response script i need to use a value from a request. I am trying to get value_2 to use it in the response.

e.g. SOAPUI mock service receives the following request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="urn:company:test">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:field_1 xmlns="urn:company:test">
         <field_2>
            <field_3>value_1</field_3>
         </field_2>
         <field_4>
            <field_5>
               <field_6>value_2</field_6>
            </field_5>
         </field_4>
          <field_4>
            <field_5>
               <field_6>value_3</field_6>
            </field_5>
         </field_4>
      </ns1:field_1>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have visited the following links, but it did not work for me.

[Access the request XML in a SOAP UI mock response script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415772/access-the-request-xml-in-a-soap-ui-mock-response-script)

[SoapUI getting request parameters in mock service script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945403/soapui-getting-request-parameters-in-mock-service-script)

Also I tried following lines and failed.

```
def req = new XmlSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContent)
context.theValue = req.field_1.field_4.field_5.field_6
```

Also please note that I use Basic Version (not Pro)

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks, Tony

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
println req.Body.field_1.field_4*.field_5.field_6
```

That should print out

```
[value_2, value_3]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it prints all values [value_1, value_2, value_3, etc]

Comment: but it works following way: context.theValue = req.Body.field_1.field_4[0].field_5.field_6 ==* Thanks a lot *==

Comment: @Tony yeah...multiple things match your query, so you need to specify which one you want

Comment: @Tony and you shouldn't get `value_1` in your output, as it does not match the path of your query...