# SOAPUI - changing request element value

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I read some articles about SOAPUI, one of them is this [SoapUI getting request parameters in mock service script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945403/soapui-getting-request-parameters-in-mock-service-script/1141843#1141843) and I think the solution I am looking for is something using Groovy.

I have a SOAP Web Service that I want to run some testes with a dynamically changing request.  This request...

```
   <soapenv:Body>
      <req:MyrRquest>
         <req:number>XPTO</req:number>
      </req:MyrRquest>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

My idea is to run a loop from a starting value increasing 1 until I reach my maximum.  And I would like to replace XPTO with this changing value.

Did anyone ever attempted this?  What is the best way to do that?

Comment: are you ok to use load test?

Comment: The idea is not a Load test because I am not testing performance but consistency with my legacy system.  So I am running from a mass of requests.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way it can be done, by the use of groovy step.

Define a test case with two test steps:

1. Test Request step(soap, the one you shown)
2. Groovy Script Step(this is the additional one which I am proposing)

Define below **three test case level custom properties** like what you needed min and max times it should be repeatedly executed and provide values as per the test and keep `CURRENT_VALUE` same as `MIN_VALUE` which is one time job. Because, `CURRENT_VALUE` that gets incremented each time and do not want to alter `MIN_VALUE` each time the test runs. That way, do not have reset the value after each time test case is executed.

- MIN_VALUE
- MAX_VALUE
- CURRENT_VALUE

Note that this cannot run individual steps i.e., the test case has to be executed in order to fulfill your need as it has to repeat the number of times, and hope that is ok for you.

In the test request, need to use the current value place holder.

Change: `<req:number>XPTO</req:number>`
To    : `<req:number>${#TestCase#CURRENT_VALUE}</req:number>`

**Here is the groovy script code:**

```groovy
//Read the test case level properties as integers
def min = context.testCase.getPropertyValue('MIN_VALUE') as Integer
def max = context.testCase.getPropertyValue('MAX_VALUE') as Integer

//Get the previous step name
def pStepName = context.testCase.testStepList[context.currentStepIndex-1].name

//min+1, because already test request is executed once
((min+1)..max).each { 

    //update the current value incremented by 1
    context.testCase.setPropertyValue('CURRENT_VALUE', it.toString())
    log.info "Running step ${pStepName} for ${it} time"

    //run the previous test step
    testRunner.runTestStepByName(pStepName)
}
//finally resetting current value to min value as test finishes
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('CURRENT_VALUE', min.toString())
```

This groovy script step basically takes care of running the first step for `n-1` times, because `step 1` already executed before groovy script test step where `n` is the total number of times required to be executed(`n = max - min`).

And as mentioned earlier, just run the test case.